# how can i change the date format in asp boiler plate 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, date-format, abp

Want to change my input type date format dddd, dd-MM-yyyy.
Any update or guidance?

try input tostring("yyyy-MM-dd") but it is default format.

Comment: Could you please share your `code snippet` so far you have now? So that we can assist you further.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want to change the format of model property,you can try to use `[DisplayFormat]`.

Comment: Thank you for all of you, but by using the format as answered below, its working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am using an asp boilerplate platform. I found that the platform only follows this date format 'yyyy-MM-dd. And this is working.